# How to add new custom Menu to NX open?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cad

Can anyone guide me on How can I add my own Custom Menu in NX-Open using C++?
I have created all UI and work flow which will follow click of a custom menu. I just need a starting point from where any user can Enter my tool.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this within your .tbr, .rtb or .men file (NX startup directory).
The startup directory depends on how your NX is configured, usually it is in your NX installation folder or on a seperate network drive.

Example: (add this in your menu file)

```
BUTTON  TEST_MENU_BUTTON
LABEL   Test Label
ACTIONS Test.dll
```